# Target not being executed when imported to the main *.proj file

Tags: msbuild, import, target

I use the TFS 2008 build facilities. I have a large MSBuild project (TFSBuild.proj) and I wanted to split it into a few files because it is becoming hard to maintain.

I found a strange behavior; when I extracted one of the targets (BeforeInitializeWorkspace) to a separate file and then imported it into the main *.proj file, it was not executed. Although, in my MSBuild log, there was information that the target has been imported and overridden, but hasn't been executed. If I have the same target defined in my main *.proj file, it is executed. Can someone explain why the target isn't executed when imported from a file?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me being stupid ;)

I had the order of `<Import>` wrong. The first file to import was my overridden target, then the `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets` was imported and overrode my target.

Anyway, changing the order helped. So now, the `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets` is the first target to import and then all my other targets.